# Não mostra a categoria

Tags: php, mysql

Meu blog está mostrando o post normalmente, menos a parte da categoria. Não sei mais o que fazer para arrumar esse problema. Alguém poderia me dar uma forcinha por favor?

```
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());
$linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
```

Abaixo mostra a parte do código:

```
                          <?php do { ?>
                            <div class="post post-row">
                                <a class="post-img" href="blog-post.html"><img src="Admin/app/webroot/files/post/imagem1/<?php echo $linhas['imagem1_dir']; ?>/<?php echo $linhas['imagem1']; ?>"></a>
                                <div class="post-body">
                                    <div class="post-meta">
                                        <a class="post-category" href="category.html"><?php echo $linhas['categoria']; ?></a>
                                        <span class="post-date"><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas['data']); ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3 class="post-title"><a href="blog-post.html"><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas['titulo_principal']); ?></a></h3>
                                    <p><?php echo utf8_encode($linhas['texto_inicial']); ?></p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <?php } while ($linhas = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)); ?>
                        </div>
```

Mas apenas essa parte não mostra, que é justamente a categoria:

```
<a class="post-category" href="category.html"><?php echo $linhas['categoria']; ?></a>
```

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados, uma chamada Posts que possui categoria_id. Já a tabela Categorias, tem id e categoria.
Alguém que possa me ajudar?
Obrigada!

Comment: Por favor, mostre a sql de consulta no banco de dados.

Comment: Creio que seja essa parte:
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
Desculpa se estiver errado, estou estudando ainda mysql.

Quando eu coloco 'categoria_id' (onde tem somente categoria) <?php echo $linhas['categoria']; ?>
aparece os ids certos, mas o nome das categorias não mostra.

Comment: Se você quer exibir dados das duas tabelas então terá que fazer um INNER JOIN entre as duas tabelas através do campo categoria id comum a ambas as tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve entender de mysql e como fazer consultas relacionando tabelas. 
Na sua tabela de posts deve ter um campo com o índice da categoria para que você consiga esse relacionamento. Por exemplo, na tabela de posts e categorias você teria um campo de id_categoria.
Então você teria o sql:

```
SELECT posts.*,categorias.categoria FROM posts
INNER JOIN categorias ON (posts.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Entendi.
Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Disponha. Se a resposta solucionou seu problema o ideal é você marcar como solução para ajudar a comunidade.